# create a unique ref for each element while renderItem() in a SectionList/ FlatList react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

This is a basic example below :

```
 renderItem: ({ item }) =>          


            <SwipeRow

              ref={(SwipeRow) => { refSwipeRow = SwipeRow }}  >

              <TouchableOpacity 
                onPress={() => {
                    refSwipeRow.closeRow()
                }
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </SwipeRow>
```

while onPress **refSwipeRow.closeRow()** is called but it only works on the last index, technically it's right because the while rendering the **ref** is getting overriden and at the end it only holds the last index reference.

How create a unique ref for each element.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When rendering `FlatList/SectionList` you should add a unique key prop to each rendered item. You can achieve this with using `keyExtractor` prop for the `FlatList and SectionList`. You can read about it more [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#keyextractor).

And for your question, you can set refs into a single object with again a unique id. Then `onPress` fired you can use that unique value to close row.

**For Example**

```
renderItem: ({ item }) => (          
              <SwipeRow
                ref={(SwipeRow) => { this.rowRefs[item.id] = SwipeRow; }}  >
                  <TouchableOpacity 
                    onPress={() => {
                      this.rowRefs[item.id].closeRow();
                    }
                  </TouchableOpacity>
              </SwipeRow>
            )
```

**Update**
To use `this.rowRefs[item.id]` you should declare it firs in component's `constructor` as an empty object like this,

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.rowRefs = {};
}
```

Comment: Thank you soo much for your response, is it mandatory to use keyExtractor?

can't I use the my own unique key in **item.id** which directly comes from the API.

Comment: Like I said in the answer, _you should add_ but it is not mandatory. And you can use any value for the key. Read the docs and look for the examples.

Comment: it gives me an error _cannot set property '1' undefine._ :(

Comment: Please update your question with what you tried and the complete error you got.

Comment: @SandeepKumar I updated my answer. Please check and see if it helps

Comment: @bennygenal it works, you saved my day :) Thank you :)