# REACT-NATIVE: how to reference textinput in Flatlist. Returning for last item alone

Tags: react-native

I have 2 TextInput in each element in Flatlist. based on the number entered in 1st TextInput, 2nd TextInput's value is changed of that particular element and vice versa. though if I enter number 1st TextInput of 1st element in Flatlist, the last element's 2nd TextInput gets changed.

infact no matter the number of elements in Flatlist, last elements TextInputs values gets changed
[image]

[image]

Note: Used this reference in my code, but no luck [create a unique ref for each element while renderItem() in a SectionList/ FlatList react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46261049/create-a-unique-ref-for-each-element-while-renderitem-in-a-sectionlist-flatli)

Here is my code:

```
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {

        passedDisputesArray: passedDisputesArray,
          disputeQuantityArray: [],
            disputeAmountsArray: [],

    };

      this.textInputDisputeQuantity = {};
    this.textInputDisputeAmount = {};
    }


    render() {
      super.render(this);
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <KeyboardAwareFlatList
            data={this.state.passedDisputesArray}
            extraData={this.state}
            windowSize={11}
            initialNumToRender={10}
            renderItem={this.renderpassedDisputesArrayList}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.transactionId}
            ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter.bind(this)}
            onEndReached={this.LoadMoreLineData}
            onEndReachedThreshold={1}
          />
        </View>
      )
    };

    renderpassedDisputesArrayList = ({ item, index }) => {
      return (
        <TouchableOpacity>
          <TextField
            ref={ref => { this.textInputDisputeQuantity[item.transactionId] = ref }}
            mode='flat'
            label='Dispute Quantity'
            placeholder="Enter Dispute Quantity"
            keyboardType='number-pad'
            value={this.state.disputeQuantityArray[index]}
            onChangeText={(text) => {
              console.log("text quantity: " + text + " quantity: " + item.quantity);
              if (parseFloat(text) > parseFloat(item.quantity)) {
                this.makeToast("Dispute quantity cannot be greater than invoiced quantity", true);
                let { disputeQuantityArray, disputeAmountsArray } = this.state;
                disputeQuantityArray[index] = "";
                disputeAmountsArray[index] = "";
                this.textInputDisputeQuantity[item.transactionId].clear();
                this.setState({ disputeQuantityArray, disputeAmountsArray, });
              }
              else {
                let { disputeQuantityArray, disputeAmountsArray } = this.state;
                disputeQuantityArray[index] = text;
                disputeAmountsArray[index] = text * item.unitPrice;
                this.setState({ disputeQuantityArray, disputeAmountsArray });
                this.textInputDisputeAmount[item.transactionId].setValue(this.state.disputeAmountsArray[index]);
              }
              console.log("disputeQuantityArray: ", this.state.disputeQuantityArray);
              console.log("disputeAmountsArray: ", this.state.disputeAmountsArray);
            }}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by replacing all places with

```
this.textInputDisputeQuantity[item.transactionId]
```

to

```
this.textInputDisputeQuantity[index]
```

Answer (score 0):

Bro, set any uniq key reference to your textInput and do not use state to update the value. you can use a dynamic values as props inside your textInputLayout's value.

Follow like this:
provide unique props like key to each row.
for ex. key = {index}

```
renderpassedDisputesArrayList = ({ item, index }) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity>
      <TextField
        key={index}
        ref={(ref) => {
          this.textInputDisputeQuantity[item.transactionId] = ref;
        }}
        mode="flat"
        label="Dispute Quantity"
        placeholder="Enter Dispute Quantity"
        keyboardType="number-pad"
        value={this.state.disputeQuantityArray[index]}
        onChangeText={(text) => {
          console.log("text quantity: " + text + " quantity: " + item.quantity);
          if (parseFloat(text) > parseFloat(item.quantity)) {
            this.makeToast(
              "Dispute quantity cannot be greater than invoiced quantity",
              true
            );
            let { disputeQuantityArray, disputeAmountsArray } = this.state;
            disputeQuantityArray[index] = "";
            disputeAmountsArray[index] = "";
            this.textInputDisputeQuantity[item.transactionId].clear();
            this.setState({ disputeQuantityArray, disputeAmountsArray });
          } else {
            let { disputeQuantityArray, disputeAmountsArray } = this.state;
            disputeQuantityArray[index] = text;
            disputeAmountsArray[index] = text * item.unitPrice;
            this.setState({ disputeQuantityArray, disputeAmountsArray });
            this.textInputDisputeAmount[item.transactionId].setValue(
              this.state.disputeAmountsArray[index]
            );
          }
          console.log(
            "disputeQuantityArray: ",
            this.state.disputeQuantityArray
          );
          console.log("disputeAmountsArray: ", this.state.disputeAmountsArray);
        }}
      />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```